# Issue on Bootstrap 3 Grid System with Small Screen Laptops

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

As Far as my understanding Bootstrap 3 classifying all landscape view ports from 13" Laptops to 24" big screens as `col-lg`-x . This is starting from 1280x800(13" Notebook) to 1920x1200 (24" Desktops). Now my problem is in order having two column like this

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4" id="leftBox"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-8" id="rightBox"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

From 19" to bigger size this layout looks perfect but on smaller size specifically on 13" the `lefBox` appears very small and the entire content are un-readable!. I tried to use the `col-md-x` classes but apparently those affect on Tablets screens

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" id="leftBox"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6" id="rightBox"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

now can you please let me know how I can come over to this issue by having diffrent column on small screen laptops?! which is between `col-md` and `col-lg`

Comment: You can either write your own media queries, or [customize the Bootstrap grid's screen size values](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

You have the code right, but have their order wrong. In order to use the code in smaller screens you should use it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

and not the other way around. First use the class of the smaller screen.